# Ubuntu, Apache, virtualhost and Access forbidden

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I made virtualhost like: [here](http://www.pgorecki.pl/content/virtual-host-na-localho%C5%9Bcie-apache-ubuntu). My directory is in my home folder. When I try to enter my new domain or anywhere I get 403 error:/

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the details of the error in the log file

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

apache probably need read access to the following documents:

```
/home/.htaccess
/home/user/.htacces
[...]
/home/user/path/to/project/.htaccess
```

Comment: so how did you choose to set up the permissions? Did you create a dedicated user?

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question in the case you are still stuck.

I presume that you have set the permissions the correct way. The next step is to check if your home folder is encrypted? If so this might be your problem. Put you files in an folder outside of the home folder and give the permissions needed to access the folder.